# How does the gmail Android App compare to the Webmail experience when using multiple gmail accounts?

Tags: settings, gmail, pop3, imap

This is a "pre-sales" question as I don't currently have an Android device. I did try out one when Android was version 1.6, but was dissappointed. I am interested to know if 2.2 or 2.3 is better.

In particular, I use Gmail as my only email client. It operates all my email accounts (3 corporate and 2 personal). Every email is sent and received via the gmail server and is therefore filed and searchable in gmail. When I compose and email, I can choose which account to send it from and it comes via the domain server (i.e. not from gmail).

My impresssion of android is that is can set up seperate email (pop, imap etc) inboxes and operate them directly with each domain server as pop/imap - but I don't want that as emails will not be kept on the gmail server and therefore filed, backed up and searchable from the webmail client.

How does email account aggregation actually work in Android - is it true Gmail Webmail handling or is it just multi-account handling direct with domainemail servers missing Gmails servers in the process?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks again for these valuable answers. I have just taken the plunge, having lost my trusty Nokia E51 in the park. Amazon are delivering an HTC Desire S in the next few days.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use the GMail app and not the Email app.  You can select what email to send from -- it shows all the addresses you have set up in GMail -- and has a surprising number of GMail's features for a mobile app.  It does go through GMail's servers and you will have your archive.  I don't think you can set up and manage POP accounts from it, but if you're not abandoning the web interface entirely then it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

There are three ways to access Gmail in Android:

1. Setup an POP/IMAP account using Email app. This is not recommended, since you lose many of Gmails' unique feature.
2. Use the Browser and Gmail's mobile view. This is not recommended, since you don't get mail notifications.
3. Setup Gmail account in the Gmail app. This is the preferred way of using Gmail on Android, the Gmail app works well with many of Gmail's unique features, such as mail search, label, archives, conversations, stars, "Send As", muting, priority inbox, etc.

> Every email is sent and received via the gmail server and is therefore filed and searchable in gmail

The Gmail app does that.

> When I compose and email, I can choose which account to send it from and it comes via the domain server (i.e. not from gmail).

I don't think you can setup "Send As" from Gmail app, but you can send an email with any "Send As" address you have configured in the webmail.

I don't think there is any major Gmail webmail features that the Android Gmail missed.